# Проверить директорию на использование

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Можно ли в C# проверить, сидит ли кто-нибудь в директории?

Мне это нужно выполнить, перед ее удалением. На мой взгляд, это самый быстрый способ проверки, нежели пытаться проверять на занятость каждый файл в директории.

В WinServer, например, во вкладке управление это можно узнать.

А есть ли какая-нибудь обертка для этого дела в C#?

Comment: Вариант удаления в `try { } catch{ }` (удалилось - ну и славно, нет - положили ошибку в лог) не подходит?

Comment: @i-one, Хотелось предотвратить все возможные ошибки, например, директория используется(Самая частая ошибка.) С использование try/catch, что-то удалится, а что-то нет.

Comment: Главная проблема любых предварительных проверок - кто-то может открыть файл сразу после проверки.

Answer (score 2):

### Вариант 1.

Попытайтесь переименовать директорию. Если в ней есть заблокированные файлы - переименовать не получится.

Этот способ не работает на Windows XP.

### Вариант 2.

Перед удалением файлов, откройте их все в режиме чтения-записи, с указанием разрешения параллельного удаления (`FileMode.Open`, `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, `FileShare.Delete`).

Если они удачно открылись - удаляйте их, а уже после удаления - закрывайте.

Если хоть один файл не удалось открыть - значит, он открыт кем-то еще. Закрывайте файлы обратно и не трогайте их.

Этот способ работает на Windows XP, спасибо [Yurii Manziuk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/206432/yurii-manziuk) за проверку.

Comment: Вариант 2 - работает

Comment: да, именно ХРюшу проверил, пока есть возможность

Comment: А почему первый способ не работает в XP?

Comment: @iluxa1810 потому что XP разрешает переименование папок в то время как внутри открыт и заблокирован файл.

Comment: А получить список юзеров в директорри никак нельзя?

Comment: @iluxa1810 можно. Но как - не знаю. Может, еще кто ответит.

Comment: Можно, наверно действительно все подряд удалять, ловить ошибку и использовать WinApi MoveFileEx.